# How can I track which element of ItemsControl caused ContexMenu to open?

Tags: wpf, avalonia

In my book editor app I need to display themes and subthemes in an hierarchical order, so I made such an markup:

```
<StackPanel>
      <ScrollViewer>
        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="auto, *" RowDefinitions="auto">
          <ItemsControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Items="{Binding Book.Themes}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                  <Button Content="{Binding Name}" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.UpdateSubthemesVisibilityCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Name}"/>
                  <ItemsControl Items="{Binding Subthemes}" IsVisible="{Binding AreSubthemesVisible}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                      <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                      </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl.ContextMenu>
                      <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Rename" />
                        <MenuItem Header="Delete"/>
                      </ContextMenu>
                    </ItemsControl.ContextMenu>
                  </ItemsControl>
                </StackPanel>
              </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ContextMenu>
              <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Rename" Command="{Binding RenameThemeCommand}" CommandParameter="...How to bind it to button which cause menu to open"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Delete"/>
              </ContextMenu>
            </ItemsControl.ContextMenu>
          </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>
      </ScrollViewer>
    </StackPanel>
```

Maybe markup isn't quite clear, but the point is that I have external ItemsControl and internal one. External one's items have structure: button (theme name) + internal ItemsControl which presents subthemes' names as buttons too.  Here is Screenshot:
[image]

Each ItemsControl has its own ContextMenu, but I can't bind them properly. I want "Rename" MenuItems to be bind to Button.Content of Button which right click caused menu to open. How should I do this here?
I am using MVVM Avalonia, but I hope in WPF it's working the same way so that I could add WPF hashtag to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add ContextMenu to ItemsControl. It needs to be added to the items ItemsControl.
This is done in ItemContainerStyle.
In such a case, in ContextMenu DataContext will contain the element on which the ContextMenu is called.

Example:

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <spec:StringCollection x:Key="strings">
            <sys:String>First</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Second</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Third</sys:String>
        </spec:StringCollection>
        <Style x:Key="ItemStyle" TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{StaticResource strings}"
                  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ItemStyle}"/>
```